# some time program works fine and some times shows height, width, layers = img.shape AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

```
img_array = []
for filename in glob.glob('/home/adnan/Downloads/*.png'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    print(img)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width,height)
    img_array.append(img)


out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 5, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

- programs some times works and some times it gives error *

Comment: Rather than putting link to an image or posting an image. Please copy paste the exact code, so that others can try out your code and help you better.

Comment: Either image is empty i.e having 0bytes or the image is supposed to be in gray scale

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) explain that

> If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix

Immediately after the `.imread()` call you will want to check for such a failure:

```
if img is None:
    continue
```

Comment: in case of failure I tried to print (img) it was printing the matrix but last was showing same error

Answer (score 0):

I found solution of this
Actually problem was coming from imread() function
I updated libpng library simply and it worked after that fin